# How to ignore [source path] linked resources in EGit?

Tags: egit

If I add linked resources to my eclipse project like this:

```
<linkedResources>
    <link>
        <name>[source path] src</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <locationURI>DOCUMENTS/Another_Project/src</locationURI>
    </link>
</linkedResources>
```

EGit show all linked files each time in commit screen.

I've tried various combination of entries in .gitignore without success. Default right click **Team -> Ignore** adds this line : **/[source path] src** to .gitignore, but it doesn't work.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I hope someone eventually answers this. I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way we solved it was manually editing the relevant .gitignore files, for a fuller answer please check my response here [answer to question 3310129](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310129/controlling-egits-treatment-of-symbolic-links/7819913#7819913)

Comment: Your solution to question 3310129 is not working for me. However, using a wildcard (*) character does the trick (see my solution below).

Answer (score 0):

Actually EGit still lacks proper treatment of Linked Resources, see [eclipse bug 333338](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333338). I've been working out a [patch to resolve this issue](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#change,3680). So if you really want EGit to gracefully ignore linked resources, you probably need to build from source and include that [patch](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#change,3680). The [EGit contributor guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/Contributor_Guide) should help you get started. Otherwise the .gitignore workaround mentioned previously may be your only option.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that we can use while waiting for this bug to be properly fixed by the EGit team. Let's say (as suggested above) that you have a linked resource defined in this way in your Eclipse `.project` file:

```
<linkedResources>
  <link>
    <name>[source path] src</name>
    <type>2</type>
    <locationURI>DOCUMENTS/Another_Project/src</locationURI>
  </link>
</linkedResources>
```

You could manually add all files and folders located under `DOCUMENTS/Another_Project/src` to the `.gitignore` file by using the `*` or `**` wildcards:

```
**/com/domain/module_name/some_package/
```

**Warning**: Since the `**` wildcard matches any level of directories, you would have to be sure that the paths and/or file names are unique and cannot be found elsewhere in the project. But if, like me, your structure uses a reverse-dns naming style followed by module name, this solution might be all you need.